# GCC-7 C++17 cannot find aligned_alloc

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocation, memory-alignment, c++17

I am trying to use [aligned_alloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc) in my C++ code but it fails to compile:

```
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-std=c11' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
vec.cpp: In function 'int main()':
vec.cpp:13:30: error: 'aligned_alloc' was not declared in this scope
   uint8_t *arr1 = (uint8_t *)aligned_alloc(16, 16);
```

I am compiling with: `g++-7 -std=c++17 vec.cpp` on `Mac OS X 10.13.3` with G++ version: `g++-7 (Homebrew GCC 7.2.0_1) 7.2.0`

`aligned_alloc` should be a part of C++17, so I'm confused why it isn't working. Is there some other way to get aligned memory in C++17?

Here is a code example that does not work:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    uint8_t *arr1 = (uint8_t *)std::aligned_alloc(16, 16);
    std::free(arr1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like gcc's libstdc++ [doesn't implement this correctly](https://godbolt.org/g/6WWesA). Instead of `std::aligned_alloc`, it's `aligned_alloc`. [This works with libc++](https://godbolt.org/g/2tyooq), though